# Executar arquivo .vbs via php dentro do servidor

Tags: php, vbs

Bom dia.
Eu tenho um arquivo em .vbs na minha maquina que desativa alguns usuários no AD da empresa. Queria saber se é possível rodar esse arquivo dentro do meu servidor via php.
Alguém já fez algo do tipo?
Tive olhando alguns posts no forum, mas não tive sucesso.

Comment: Se não tiver problema com as credenciais ou permissão pode fazer isso chamando uma linha de comando no php.

Comment: Pelo que sei, não consegue executar ficheiros no sistema em nenhum browser, excepto no IE.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252913/open-an-exe-file-through-a-link-in-a-html-file

Comment: exec('wscript "/var/www/html/laraluiz/public/Vbscript/Bloquear_Usuario.vbs"'); tentei assim mas não obtive sucesso.

Comment: Apareceu algum erro? vc quer rodar um vbs no linux?

Comment: Não me retorna nenhum erro. Sim, não é possível?

Comment: Luiz, execute `exec('wscript "/var/www/html/laraluiz/public/Vbscript/Bloquear_Usuario.vbs‌​"',$output);` depois de um `var_dump` em `$output` para pegar o retorno da execução.

Comment: Me retorna isso array(0) { }. Mas acabei de descobrir que servidor linux não vai conseguir rodar um arquivo .vbs.

Comment: Utilizando o IE eu consegui executar esse script, mas com o aplicativo em minha maquina. <script>
 var shell = new ActiveXObject( 'WScript.shell' );
 shell.run( 'C:\\Users\\luiz.ceolin\\Desktop\\Vbscrip\\Bloquear_Usuario.vbs', 1, true );
</script>